# Excel interop: updating non-contiguous cells using only one excel interop function call

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I would like to update multiple cells very quickly using c# excel interop com object.  I have read at length about how to do it for contiguous cells but the cells I am trying to update are non-contiguous.

Suppose I have to update cells A1, B2, C3 with the values 1, 2, 3 respectively

The code I have written is:

```
Excel.Range rng = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B2,C3")
var data = new string[3];
data[0] = "1";
data[1] = "2";
data[2] = "3"; 
rng.Value2 = data;
```

The result is cells A1, B2 and C3 are updated with the same value of 1 and not the expected 1,2 and 3 respectively.

On close inspection using visual studio watch function it appears the rng.Value2 is a singular value and not an array.

So my question is how do I update the spreadsheet for non-contiguous cells using one excel interop function call?

Comment: after some testing I'm not sure it's possible; Excel won't write a block unless it's a contiguous 2D area. but it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA it is really easy. Also tested with C++ automation :

```
Sub Test()
Dim newRng As Range
 Set newRng = Application.Union(Range("A1:b18"), Range("e4:e5"))
 newRng.Value = 10
End Sub
```

Comment: can I assign different values to each cell in newRng?